# SQL JOIN statement with two fields equal to one [CodeIgniter]

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to put together a SQL statement which pulls the names of employees that have a certain title and how many labor hours that they currently have in total for a total of the current week. I am working with two different tables, so I assume that I would need to use JOIN in this case, however my dilemma is that I would need to join two fields from TABLE A to one field on TABLE B. Is this possible?

See below for my code (so far):

```
public function get_all_techs_with_hours()
        {
            // get all technicians
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('employees');
            $this->db->where('role', 'Body Technician');
            $this->db->or_where('role', 'Paint Technician');
            $this->db->or_where('role', 'Combo Technician');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query;
        }
```

In this case, `employees` is TABLE A and `jobs` is TABLE B. I need to JOIN TABLE B to TABLE A based on `jobs.body_tech` matching `employees.first_name and employees.last_name`. Atleast, I think I do. I'm sure I'm going about this the hardest approach possible, but I can't seem to find any helpful manual to learn how to do this. In the end, all I would like to do is combine all hours for each technician and add to the same array using two different tables.

Comment: Upload dB structure...

Comment: you can write `from('employees a')` and `select('a.first_name')` etc...

Comment: employees> id, first_name, last_name, email, address, address2, phone, role, hours_max, hours, level ... and jobs > id, repair_order, first_name, last_name, address, city, state, zip_code, phone, vin, year, make, model, start_date, promise_date, body_hours, paint_hours, insurance, body_tech, paint_tech

Comment: @Vickel I can do that, but my question would still be unanswered. How could I write a 'where' statement to match two fields against one? Is this possible? Reason is, employees have a unique ID, but jobs are identified to a tech by NAME, not by their ID, which I may have to go back and change that to make it easier to manage later on.

Comment: there should always be some kind of ID to related different table, concerning join: this has helped me a lot to understand: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: hint: if you add employee_id in your table jobs, then you can `join('jobs b', 'a.id=b.employee_id','left')`

Comment: I should have done it right in the first place. Then, it would have been easier at this point. I'll just chalk that one up as a novice mistake and learn from it.

Comment: this is another obligatory read: [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)